# Is there a way to download SnapBridge NEF images from iPhone to a pc?

Tags: raw, snapbridge

Is there a way to download NEF files stored in Nikon’s SnapBridge in an iPhone into a pc? If forwarding, SB crops & converts them into a jpg.

Comment: iTunes File Sharing section may be able to do it. Can't test as I don't have a snapbridge capable camera… or a PC ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhiJg.jpg

Comment: Are you sure they're still NEF files when they're on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of "native" way to sync/transfer photos from iPhone to PC. But you can try side channels like

- [Google Drive](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-drive/id507874739), upload photos there, open Google drive and PC and download them
- Also [Nikon Image Space](https://www.nikonimagespace.com/) (almost the same as above)
- send photos via mail to other account and download on PC
- connect iPhone and PC to the same WiFi network, on PC share
  (read/write) folder and use [this manual](https://osxdaily.com/2019/11/04/how-connect-smb-share-iphone-ipad-files-app/) to view and save photos
  there.

Comment: Thank you! All these possible solutions you suggested end up in the same cropped jpg image

Comment: @JoseRestrepo, are you sure you have on you phone the RAW files? This option (to download RAW) files must be activated and do not work when use Bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. SB clearly labels the RAW images.

Comment: Have you try to find the files with kind of file manager (in iOS)? And do you have any reason not to get them from camera's storage card?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - 1) iPhones don't have storage cards. 2) Windows does not integrate iPhones like Macs do. The images will be in the phone's 'pictures' DCIM structure, which on Windows has to be mounted like an external drive. On Mac they are integrated into the Apple Photos structure, so don't need mounting like an 'external drive'. iTunes can handle File Sharing operations, but only if the app has that enabled. Alternatively, they may be visible in the phone's "Files" app, but again, Windows cannot integrate that natively. If the OP has tried your 4th point then the Files app isn't storing them.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I know i* do not have storage cards, I talk about camera card. And if the files are visible via Files app they can be copied (IMHO) to external storage as Google drive, Nikon Image space or SMB share.

Comment: Sorry, misread 'camera's card. My bad. Yes, if Files app has them then they can be shared by many methods, but the OP says they're not in Files, so my guess is they're either in the app's storage or in Photos. The older Nikon WMU app puts them in Photos, so a Mac will just see them the same way it sees any iPhone photos, Windows has to mount it as a removable disk somehow [never really used it on Win, it's too much faff ;) If they're in the app's storage, then iTunes should find them.

Comment: @JoseRestrepo,  do you have any reason not to get them from camera's storage card?

Comment: I found the NEF files stored in a SD card and no longer need them. However, I think SB should enable users to download native images to a pc. To me, it is a no brainer and is a feature many Nikon users will appreciate.  Sometimes I think Nikon has disregarded their customers to the extent to push them into other more customer-friendly competitors.

Comment: @JoseRestrepo, do you have any reason not to get them from camera's storage card? – 
Romeo Ninov


Yes, there is a myriad of reasons for this.  In my case, my sd became corrupted and had to reformat it. Luckily, I found nd a back up with the nef images.

Comment: @JoseRestrepo have you actually tried iTunes, or the phone mounted as an external drive yet? It's no good complaining about what Nikon may or may not do; no-one here can fix that.

Comment: In Japan, (good) hardware designers are almost deified. Software designers, on the other hand, are looked upon as lower level blue-collar laborers. That's the main reason Japanese camera makers are so far behind on software. It's not a prestigious occupation there.

Comment: @MichaelC - there is more than a grain of truth in that. I spent a decade working for a Japanese hardware company… in the software/firmware division. Our solution was to run the division from Europe, where the distinction doesn't apply the same way.